# Anyone know significance of 18 in path to God?

Tags: brahman

We have Mahabharata lasting upto - 18 days
Bhagavad Gita - 18 chapters
Puranas - 18 Puranas
Ayyapan - 18 steps
Siddhas - primarily 18 siddhars

Is there a significance in 18? Probably 18 steps we need to take towards supreme Godhead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Numbers 18, 108, 1008, 10008 are all multiples of 9 which is a mystic
>   number. All multiples of 9 added together ultimately become number 9.
>   This can be verified (16x9=144; 1+4+4=9). The mystic number 9 is
>   arrived as follows: The universe is constituted of the three factors -
>   time, space and causation. The universe is constituted of the three
>   Gunas (ingredients) - sattva, rajas and tamas. The universe is
>   constituted of the three functions - creation, preservation and
>   destruction. This three times three making nine has made nine a mystic
>   number. The number nine exhausts the definition of the phenomenal
>   universe.
>
> Twice nine or eighteen makes the Mahabharata scheme complete. The
>   eighteen Parvas define in detail the career of man on earth. The
>   eighteen chapters in the Gita make Yoga philosophy complete. The
>   eighteen day war makes the warrior's exploits complete. Eighteen are
>   the divisions of the armies of the contending parties -Pandavas and
>   Kauravas with one having seven and the other eleven divisions. Thus
>   all the available human forces mobilized were eighteen in number.
>
> The Mahabharata is thus an exposition of the human possibilities and
>   achievements graded into eighteen, the first multiple of nine. The
>   higher multiples of nine signify further ranging into divine regions.

REF:Swami Chidbhavananda in his commentary on the Gitas

Comment: Yeah, that's good source of transcendental answer ! Looks all Universal function is said in it!

Answer (score 3):

Shatprashno upanishand Says about saddhaso kala god upasena that explains what is 16 kala to do upasena ?

No. 18 is Naryanaa
 No. 17 is Lakshmi 
 no. 16 mukhya prana Jiva kala abhimani
 no. 15 sharadha i.e. Bharathi wife of mukhya prana (belif system) 
 no. 14 Garuda, shesha and Rudra (abhimani for shravana, vak and manas)
 no. 13 Krishna shanmahisi(Shri Jambavathi, Shri Bhadra, Shri Nila, Shri KAlimdhi, Shri Mithravimdha, Shri LaxaNa)
 no. 12 wife of garuda suparni, wife of shesha varuni and wife of Parvathi
 no. 11 Indra, Kama
 no. 10 akhamkarika Prana, indras wife 
 and so on.. In short 18 steps to reach god. you need climb up the steps means you need to get anugraha of each devatha to reach the final step. 
 Here upto 16 you can worship to climb up to the step 17 and 18 are more or less the same.. because Lakshmi avykhtha similar to Narayna but not equal, so you can get Naraya na through 16.

that is why sage vyas designed gita, mahabharatha and puranas to be eighteen insisting on devatha tartamya… this is clearly insisted in tattvada as propounded by Madhvacharya.. Namo madhva guru Namo vayu avathare Namo Jiva dharni Namo adhyandhyalavae

Sree Bharathi ramana mukhyapranagratha krishnarpnamasthu